# WS 2008 R2 get process by id

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, process, application-pools, eventviewer

I have received the following message in the event viewer:

> A worker process with process id of '10088' serving application pool 'mypoolapp' has requested a recycle because the worker process reached its allowed processing time limit.

I get this return from powershell:

```
PS C:\> Get-Process -Id 10088
Get-Process : Cannot find a process with the process identifier 10088.
At line:1 char:12
+ Get-Process <<<<  -Id 10088
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (10088:Int32) [Get-Process], ProcessCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenId,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
```

How to find out who the process/program was with id 10088?

Comment: A quick google for "Get process by ID" will answer this.

Answer (score 1):

According [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process) you do all right, but looks like, when you try to find process, it's finish it work and you receive error.

Comment: Yeah, I think there must be a log or some kind of history regarding windows processes, especially when this process terminates an IIS application pool.